# Building a Cantor set with positive Lebesgue Measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

> Changing the lengths of the intervals excluded during the construction of the ternary Cantor set, show that is possible to build a compact, totally disconnected and perfect set (a Cantor set) with positive Lebesgue measure.

I have no idea on how to solve this question. It seems also counter-intuitive to me there is a Cantor set whose Lebesgue measure is positive.

**Question:**

How should I solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such a set is called a "fat Cantor set," and can be constructed by removing the middle $1/2^{n+1}$ of each interval, where $n$ is the stage in the construction; i.e., first the middle fourth, then the middle eighth, then the middle sixteenth, and so on.

Comment: @AlexS But the measure is going to be zero which is not positive right?

Comment: Do a simple Google search for "fat Cantor set." you will find many sources showing how such a thing is constructed, and how the measure is positive, not zero.